# Jquery animation isn't waiting until it finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, web

I have this function in my website:

```
$(document).on('submit','form.contactform',function(){
$(".contactTable tr:last-child td:first-child").animate({
    'padding-left' : 5
}, 2000, function(){
    var url = "contactSubmit.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $("#contactform").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        success: function()
        {
            //window.location = 'index.php?send='.'succ'; // show response from the php script.
        },
       fail: function()
       {
           alert("An error has ocurred! :O");
       }
    });
});
return false;
```

});

What I'm trying to do is that when the user clicks on the submit button, I animate a little car to the left, and after that I submit the form. (Yes, this is homework).
But what is happening is that the form is being sent before the animation finishes..
What is the problem?

EDIT:
changed to:

```
$("#contactform").submit( function() {
    var url = "contactSubmit.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        beforeSend:  $(".contactTable tr:last-child td:first-child").animate({'padding-left' : 5}, 2000),
        data: $("#contactform").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        success: function()
        {
            window.location = 'index.php?send='.'succ'; // show response from the php script.
        },
       error: function()
       {
           alert("An error has ocurred! :O");
       }
    });
    return false;
});
```

But now nothing happens and the form is just sent

EDIT 2:
This is the html for the table:

```
<form id= "contactform" class="contactform" method="post" action="contactSubmit.php">
    <table class="contactTable">
        <tr><td>Name</td> <td><input class="inputField" placeholder="John Doe" type="text" name="name" required></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Email</td><td><input class="inputField" type="text" placeholder="example@example.com" 
                   title="Please enter a valid email." name="email" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+@[a-zA-Z]+.[a-zA-Z]+(.[a-zA-Z]+)?">
                        </td></tr>

        <tr><td>Topic</td> <td>  <select class="inputField" name="topic">
                <option value="great">Compliment!</option>
                <option value="good">Neutral</option>
                <option value="bad">Bad!</option>
                <option value="other">What?</option>
        </select></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Car</td> <td> <select class="inputField" name="car">
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                </select></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Message</td><td><textarea class="inputField" name="msg" 
                                          placeholder="Your message here." required></textarea></td></tr>
        <tr><td><img src="resources/littleCar.png" alt="Little Car" class="littlecar"></td>
            <td><input type="submit" class="submitButton" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

and I have another jquery function for the field checking:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').h5Validate();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Attach the event to the form itself, instead of the document, and use the `beforeSend` in AJAX as such, and there's no 'fail' - that's supposed to be 'error'.

```
$("#contactform").submit( function(e) 
{
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent default behavior
  var url = "contactSubmit.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    beforeSend: /* animation here */, 
    data: $("#contactform").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
    success: function()
    {
      //window.location = 'index.php?send='.'succ'; // show response from the php script.
    },
    error: function()
    {
      alert("An error has ocurred! :O");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: you mean to change this line: $(document).on('submit','form.contactform',function() with: $("#contactform").submit( function() ?
Now it is not doing the animation at all..

Comment: sorry, updated the answer. use the beforeSend in the ajax call.

Comment: edited my question.. still the form is being sent and the animation is not shown..

Comment: Edited the answer once again to add prevent default behavior of the form. Note that the submit function now has an 'e' parameter that stands for the event itself. Please try it.

Comment: I tried it.. but the form is still being sent and the function is not even being called.. (I inserted an alert first in the function and it isn't being fired..)

Comment: if it isn't being fired, then probably the selector is not correct. For that we should see your underlying html structure.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see wrong is that the `data` value is set to `#contactform`, not `.contactform`. Other than that, maybe your table cell doesn't allow more padding or the padding is not pronounced enough to notice.

Here's a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vbk6H/)** with a more pronounced version of `padding-left`.

Answer (score 0):

I can clearly see two issues in your code, the first is that you should write your animation with a callback function to handle some stuff after the animation is complete. This can be done with the `complete` option of the `animate()` function.
The second point to notice is that you may change `padding-left` to `paddingLeft` as this solved the case for me multiple times:

```
$(document).on('submit','form.contactform',function(e){
  $(".contactTable tr:last-child td:first-child").animate({
    paddingLeft: "+=5",
    duration: 2000,
    complete: function()
    {
      var url = "contactSubmit.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $("#contactform").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        success: function()
        {
          //window.location = 'index.php?send='.'succ'; // show response from the php script.
        },
        fail: function()
        {
          alert("An error has ocurred! :O");
        }
      });
    }
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```